# How do I change the color of text from a radio button?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm making a segmented switch and I'm trying to use transition to change the color of text, but for some reason the text color change isn't working.

https://jsfiddle.net/zp2z2bvw/1/

This is the CSS styling:

```
#Favorites_Switch:checked ~ #Selected_Container {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transition: all .15s ease;
border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

#Favorites_Switch:checked ~ #Favorites_Text {
color: #38D1A9;
transition: color .2s ease;
}

#Favorites_Switch:checked ~ #All_Text {
color: #FFFFFF;
transition: color .2s ease;
}

#All_Switch:checked ~ #Selected_Container {
position: absolute;
left: 0%;
transition: all .15s ease;
}
```

This is the html.

```
<div id="Segmented_Control">

    <input type="radio" name="Switch" value="All" id="All_Switch" class="Radio_Switch"/>
    <input type="radio" name="Switch" value="Favorites" id="Favorites_Switch" class="Radio_Switch"/>

    <div id="Selected_Container">
    </div> <!-- Selected Container -->

    <label for="All_Switch">
        <div class="Switch_Containers" id="All_Container">
            <p class="Switch_Text" id="All_Text">All</p> <!-- All Switch -->
        </div> 
    </label> <!-- All Switch Label -->

    <label for="Favorites_Switch">
        <div class="Switch_Containers" id="Favorites_Container">
            <p class="Switch_Text" id="Favorites_Text">Favorites</p> <!-- Favorites Switch -->
        </div> <!-- Favorites Container -->
    </label>

</div> <!-- Segmented Control -->
```

I can't figure out why the font color won't change when I press on the label divs.

Comment: Hi there, you can google it, you will find something out there :) i did something like this 3 days ago.

Comment: I could be wrong but I am sure you need some javascript to do this..

Comment: @Ljubisa no, you can do it with pure CSS. Transitions and transformations are fantastic and really reduce the need for a lot of JS

Comment: @Ljubisa Yep, this is definitely possible. See the answer below.

Comment: Yess  pure css will be the best option n not js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working because the `input` checkbox elements are not siblings with the text elements (`#Favorites_Text`/`#All_Text`). You need to select the sibling `label` elements, and then select the descendant text elements from there.

In other words, you would change:

```
#Favorites_Switch:checked ~ #Favorites_Text { ... }
#Favorites_Switch:checked ~ #All_Text { ... }
```

to:

```
#Favorites_Switch:checked ~ label #Favorites_Text { ... }
#Favorites_Switch:checked ~ label #All_Text { ... }
```

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qyr4qLay/)

```
#Favorites_Switch:checked ~ label #Favorites_Text {
  color: #38D1A9;
}

#Favorites_Switch:checked ~ label #All_Text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

As a side note, I also added the transition to the element `.Switch_Text` so that the transition occurs before and after the checkboxes are checked.

If the transition is added when the checkboxes are checked, then the transition will only occur when unchecking them.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! Now that you mention that, I had a similar issue before with siblings with checked and not(checked) with something else, I'm not sure why I didn't think of it!